# How to convert a column using LAG function into to_char ('mm/dd/yyyy') format

Tags: postgresql

I have a column which is using lag function and I want to convert that column to 'mm/dd/yyyy' format and convert it to text.
`select to_char(LAG(time,1),'MM/DD/YYYY'::text) OVER (PARTITION BY a,b,c DESC) AS time from emp`
but i am getting an error

ERROR: syntax error at or near "to_char"

Comment: `OVER` applies to `LAG`, not `TO_CHAR

Answer (score -1):

Change the query to

```
select to_char(LAG(time,1) OVER (PARTITION BY a,b,c DESC) ,'MM/DD/YYYY'::text) AS time 
from emp
```

`LAG(time,1) OVER (PARTITION BY a,b,c DESC)` will return the previous date. `to_char(...,'MM/DD/YYYY'::text)` will format it in the US-only format